# undefined method `new' for "Rack::RawUpload":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rich-text-editor

I'm using `gem 'rich', GitHub: 'bastiaanterhorst/rich'` in gem file, 
after running bundle install when I'm running `rails generate rich:install`
I'm getting error this

```
> /home/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:35:in
> `build': undefined method `new' for "Rack::RawUpload":String Did you
> mean?  next (NoMethodError)   from
> /home/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in
> `block in build'  from
> /home/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in
> `each'    from
> /home/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in
> `inject'  from
> /home/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in
> `build'   from
> /home/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:508:in
> `block in app'    from
> /home/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in
> `synchronize'     from
> /home/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in
> `app'     from
> /home/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:45:in
> `block in <module:Finisher>'  from
> /home/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
> `instance_exec'
```

I'm not getting the solution for this

```
> undefined method `new' for "Rack::RawUpload":String
```

however i also tried gem `'rack-raw-upload', :git => 'git://github.com/tb/rack-raw-upload.git'`
but still getting the same error.

Comment: Where you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kreativgebiet/rich/issues/173

This is a known issue if you are using CarrierWave.

Comment: HI, you didn't get my point. let me explain again.
1 - added `gem 'rich', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.5'`
2 - bundle install
3 -rails generate rich:install
here after running step i m getting error 

`/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:35:in `build': undefined method `new' for "Rack::RawUpload":String`